# Is there some way of taking advantage of code reuse in this example?

Tags: java, algorithm, array, set

I am implementing a set, using an array as the backend.

Here is how I declared it (and some method implementations):

```
public class Set {
            private int[] elementData;
            private int size;
               ....
          public void remove(int value) {
             for(int count = 0; count < size; count ++) {
                    if(elementData[count] == value) {
                        elementData[count] = elementData[size - 1];
                        size --;
                        break;
                    } 
              }
           }
          public boolean contains(int value) {
             for(int count = 0; count < size; count ++) {
                 if(elementData[count] == value) {
                    return true;
                 }
            }
            return false;   
        }
   }
```

I tested these methods with the JUnit testing framework and they both ran fine and worked. However I am trying to improve code reuse because I see the same iteration and a test condition in both methods, that is

```
for(int count = 0; count < size; count ++) {
            if(elementData[count] == value) {
```

But both methods perform different operations if they make it into a conditional block, one returns while the other moves elements and then breaks. Is there a way to reduce code redundancy here or is that not necessary?

Comment: The title  of your post should be the function of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend creating an `indexOf` method, that returns the index of the value found.

```
private boolean indexOf(int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (elementData[i] == value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Then you can check if `indexOf` returns something other than -1. If it does, use the index returned to do what you need to do.

Additionally, you should really look over your indentation. And `count` is a bad name for a loop variable as count means the same thing as `size`. Use `i` or `index` as a loop variable instead.

Comment: counter better?

Answer (score 5):

You can absolutely refine the code to reuse the for loop. You can put the for loop in a function, which take the int value as input and return the index of value. Let's call it "iteration". If not found the value in elementData, just return -1 instead.

```
public int getIndex(int value) { 
    for(int count = 0; count < size; count ++) {
        if(elementData[count] == value) {
            return count;
        }
    } 
    return -1;
}
```

In your remove function, if you get -1 as the return value of the "iteration" function, do nothing. If you get a positive value, remove elementData[index]. Similar in the contains function.